# How to create a function that applies individually to each variable number of arguments

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, arguments

**Abstract** I have a function `objectName` that gets `SymbolName` and value. I would like to apply this to many variables at once with another function that applies to each argument with unknown number of them. I would prefer not to list them but just throw them in as arguments much like the function 'Plus[a,b,c,...]' but would output results as pairs in a list `{{name[a],value[a]},{name[b],value[b]},{name[c],value[c]},...}`. I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
objectName = Function[Null, {SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]], Evaluate[symbol]}, {HoldFirst}];
dataIn[#__] := Function[Null, objectName[#__], Listable];
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
objectName = Function[Null,
  ReleaseHold[
   Map[
    Function[Null, {SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]] , #}, HoldAll],
    Hold[{##}],
    {2}
    ]
   ],
  HoldAll
  ]
```

Example:

```
a = 1;
 objectName[a, b, c, d]
```

> {{"a", 1}, {"b", b}, {"c", c}, {"d", d}}

Comment: thank you but I need variable number of arguments to work for the `dataIn[]`.

Comment: @Henrik-Schumaker yes of course. but it needs to work in the `dataIn` so it could create rows of name-value pairs for presentation of variables and their values. an auxiliary function `dataOut` would present the results of calculations in name-value pairs.